# Execute a function every minute while not blocing hardware interrupts?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, interrupt

I'm making an energy meter using a Raspberry Pi, which gets its reading from a flashing LED (1000 flashes/kWh). It counts the flashes for 60 seconds through an interrupt and then it sends the data to a database. This works great, none of the flashes are missed this way, but because it just constantly checks if 60 seconds have passed it pegs the given thread to a 100% which is less than optimal for a 24/365 usecase.

Here is the important part of the code:

```
sampleFreqency = 60 #seconds
flashCount = 0
time1 = time.time()

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  

def flashCounter(self):
    global flashCount
    if not GPIO.input(17):
        print("Light!")
        flashCount = flashCount + 1

GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.BOTH, callback=flashCounter, bouncetime=50)

while True:
    if time.time() > time1+sampleFreqency:
        energy = flashCount #Wh
        power = energy * 0.36/(sampleFreqency/10) # kW
        print("Power: " + str(power) + "kW, Energy: " + str(energy) + "Wh")
        logData(power, energy)
        flashCount = 0
        time1 = time.time()
```

I have tried using the `threading Timer` module without success, as it blocks everything else until it runs.

Comment: I'd try putting a short time delay at the end of your while loop. 1ms would be enough to break to 100% utilisation

Comment: That is true, but then the CPU would spend most of its time sleeping, and in that state it can't process GPIO interrupts. Already tried that.

Comment: I have written code for the pi where the main loop is nothing but a short time delay and the GPIO interrupts have worked perfectly. The CPU doesn't actually sleep, it just lets the scheduler of the OS know that the specific program doesn't need to do anything for a time period. Interrupts will still work.

Comment: I have just tried using `time.sleep(0.001)` again, but I got the same result. In terrupts only get executed randomly, as while it is in sleep they don't get processed. Could you please elaborate how you got them working? I have googled many solutions but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out interrupts in fact do trigget while the program is doing `time.sleep()` , only my code was not functioning as I would have wanted it to. I have rewritten the ISR like this:

```
def flashCounter(self):
    global flashCount
    print("Light!")
    flashCount = flashCount + 1

GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING, callback=flashCounter, bouncetime=50)
```

Now it works flawlessly.
The issue was that for sensing the blinking I'm using a photoresistor which has a slow reaction time, and when the interrupt triggered on the falling edge, the voltage probably has not had fallen to a level which would read as low, so the if statement did not get fulfilled.